# While making custom URL, Meta tags is not displaying custom URL?

Tags: 7, uri, meta-tags

I'm using drupal 7 and using meta-tag module, while inserting the custom url I'm not able to get the custom url display in the source code.

If i insert in meta-tag page title: `user [node:title] | [site:name]` its display the url in source code,
but if i insert this kind of url `hello drupal` its not displaying this url.

what should I do so that my custom url can be display while serching the source code in browser.

Comment: Try clearing your cache. I tried by adding "test" in some metatag and it showed up after a cache clear.

Comment: @Ben "hello drupal" is not working please give me any other solution.